# Add/remove routes in Linux from kernel space

Tags: linux-kernel

Is there way to manipulate routes from linux kernel module ?
Add or remove default route from main table, for example. Maybe kernel has some exported methods?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this a programming question? Can you make that a bit clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd refer you to 32th-36th chapters of the "Understanding Linux Network Internals" book.